# drupal display the rest category article

Tags: drupal, module

i have create a category CMS,and add three terms to it (drupal,joomla,wordpress). when i create an article which belongs to drupal.now i want to show the rest drupal's articles(belongs to the term of drupal ) at the bottom of the article .is there a module to get this or how to write the code to get that.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Similar by terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms) module will do what you want.

Coding this is not a bad way to learn some drupal coding skills. If you want to do your own, post here and I can give you pointers.

*edit*

You will need to implement [hook_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) to create and define your block.

I suggest that you start with outputing some dummy text to prove to yourself that you have got it working.

You can then use [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) to load the object, and make sure that you only return something on node pages.

As part of your node object. Use var_dump on what is returned from menu_get_object to see what is there, there will be a taxonomy, which you can interrigate to get the appropriate term.

Then you can use [taxonomy_select_nodes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/6) to get the nodes.

Let us know you if you run into any issues.

Comment: i want to do it by myself,you're my hero. expect you can give me some tips.